# Likelihood of a set of ranks

Tags: ranking, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, likelihood

I'm sorry if I cannot formulate the problem precisely.

Let us consider an ordered set $Q$ with $n_q$ elements, and a number of its (possibly overlapping) subsets $B_1, \dots, B_k$. For a given $i$, one is interested in the question whether the ranks of set $B_i$ are uniformly distributed in $Q$, or whether the ranks of the elements of $B_i$ are lower than of the elements of $Q$. Note that the number of elements $n_i$ of the set $B_i$ can vary wildly.

So, say below we have Q, sorted from rank 1 to 10. Elements of Q which do not belong to some $B_i$ are shown as "o", elements which *do* belong to that $B_i$ are shown as "O":

$B_1$: ooOooOooOO
$B_2$: OOOOOooooo
$B_3$: OOoOoooooo

In the real-world application, $Q$ has $10^4$ to $10^5$ elements, and the sizes of $B_i$ vary between 10 and $10^4$. Some of the $B_i$ are clearly biased compared to a more or less uniform distribution -- like in example $B_2$ above. Some of them less so, like $B_3$ above.

My ultimate goal, however, is to order $B_1 \dots B_k$ by their deviation from a uniform distribution of ranks in $Q$.

One possibility is just to use a Mann-Whitney U test on each of $B_i$, and sort $B_i$ by the respective p-values. The problem is that the power of this test will be very different for different $n_i$. Thus a subset with many elements can slightly deviate from the uniform distribution and nonetheless have a p-value lower than a much smaller set with a larger deviation. Consider this example:

$Q = \{ 1 \dots 1000 \}$

The elements of $B_1$ are the first 10 elements of $Q$:

$B_1 = \{ 1 \dots 10 \}$, $n_1=10$, $p_1 < 10^{-7}$

The elements of $B_2$ are sparsely distributed within the first 500 elements of $Q$:

$B_2 = \{ 50, 55, 60, \dots, 450\}$, $n_2=81$, $p_2 < 10^{-15}$

So if I order them by $p$-value, I will often get results which have a modest effect size (i.e., modest difference in ranks), but a large number of elements in that particular $B_i$, **ranked before** other, more interesting cases where size of $B$ is smaller.

Another option is to sort the $B_i$ according to an estimate of the effect size, for example, the U statistics. This, however, gives random flukes at the beginning of the list, which are not interesting.

What is interesting? It is a combination of two things: statistical significance and effect size. As a biologist, I can only describe my practice: I am *not* interested in something which has a large effect size, but is non-significant. Likewise, I'm not interested in something with a small effect size, but a small p-value.

Look, imagine you have been doing a number of t-tests and you ask yourself the question: which of them are giving me the most relevant (i.e., interesting for the experimentalist) results? The ones with a low p-value may nonetheless correspond to a very small difference in means, while the ones where the means show a huge difference might be not significant at all. If I want to sort these results, what sorting should I adopt?

I thought that maybe instead of applying a test-like or test-based procedure, I could calculate AIC values or evidence ratios for the different subsets. For this, I would have to obtain a likelihood function for the subsets, and I don't know how to tackle it. **Which is my actual question.**

Comment: Do you want to say that you have Q consisting of ranks (positive integers 1...n) and you want to work out some form of standardized index assesing a degree to which an arbitrary subset of arbitrary size, from Q, is far from being a collection of consecutive integers?

Comment: No, a standardized index assesing a degree to which an arbitrary subset of arbitrary size is far from being a collection of *random* integers.

Comment: Note that the Mann-Whitney conditions on the two $n$s

Comment: So, you actually aiming to assess if a subset is representative - as a random sample - of Q?

Comment: No, I'm aiming to order the subset by the magnitude of their deviation from a uniform distribution of their ranks in $N$.

Comment: So, the uniform subset is with ranks (which are the values of Q) equally spaced; far not uniform - somehow far not equally spaced? Did I now get you? (If it is so, there's a need to conceptualize that "somehow").

Comment: I have tried to clarify a bit my problem. Terribly sorry for the confusion; at least I can say that the problem is real and important for experimental work.

Comment: I'm too, sorry for being so incomprehensive. `the ranks of set Bi are uniformly distributed in N, or whether the ranks of the elements of Bi are lower than of the elements of N`. _What_ is N? You never defined it clearly. Also, _how_ "ranks of set Bi" are obtained? Is that the ordinal statistics (the ranks) how they are in Q? Or what? If gave the example with real data instead of OOoo the question would be much clearer.

Comment: @ttnphns gosh, I'm so stupid. First I used "N", but to avoid confusion (sic) I changed it to Q... but forgot to change it in all instances. I am not going to give a real world example, amongst other reasons because the data set is so large. However this is a problem similar to enrichment analysis of GO terms, except that I cannot define a "foreground" and "background" set for a hypergeometric test.